# HTML/CSS - Select child directly after an h2 element

Tags: html, css

For example, I have following short HTML code:

```
<div ...>
  <h2 class="test">...</h2>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Is it somehow possible to get the child-element (**p** in this example) after the **h2**?

I thought of something like

```
.test < p
.test + p
```

(For my specific topic/task I have to "select" the child after h2 like, if that is even possible.)

Comment: *Thought of something like* --> why thinking instead of testing?

Answer (score -1):

It was easier than I thought:

```
div:has(.test) {
   p {...}
}
```

Comment: Is this valid CSS or is it some extension like SCSS?

Comment: more or less valid. the `:has()` selector is still not supported by all browsers (mainly not by FF). While with newest updates of browser you can nest in very limited way. Chrome still has problems when nesting anything else then classes or ID's

Comment: That’s not valid syntax for [css nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting). It looks like SASS.

Comment: It also selects *any* `p` in *any* div which also has a descendant with the test class. It doesn't meet the "after" requirement.